# Is there an existing plugin or a way to round up all posts without a featured image uploaded?

Tags: wordpress

We are using a glossary plugin to manage our terms and definitions in our WordPress site, so this uses a custom post type called glossary.

Is there an easier way for us to track all posts under this custom post type that don't have a featured image uploaded?

Comment: Do you have a preferred method for identifying said posts? SQL query, WP CLI, `WP_Query`?